# Check for unique rows, but ignore one particular column

Tags: ssms

I have an XML document, that looks like this:

Column A to S with headers, and there are 1922 rows.

This is an backup of some SMS, and I want to get rid of duplicates.

The problem is, that the Time in the readable_date header has been messed up.
There is nothing wrong with the date, but the clock time is wrong, so I have split that column in three, with Year, day and clock.

I know I can use a standard filter, but it only looks for unique rows in a single column.
What I want to perform, is to make a row check similar to this:

F(x)=Check if Column 2A to (infinate) is equal to Column 3A to (infinate), but ignore column(R). IF True, then delete Column 3A to (infinate) Otherwise Check IF column 2A to (infinate) is equal Column 4A to (infinate) and so on.

I need to ignore a particular column in a row every time, and need to do this for a complete sheet. And the formula check should apply for every row, when the first one is done checking for duplicates...

If anyone else has a better solution, please say so.
Anyway, anyone who can help?

You are right that I can to that usually, but for really short messages, this doesn't apply, as the Message " Hey" can be sent by multiple people, or one person multiple days, and that isn't a duplicate.

The rows need to be checked completely in the first attempt, and ignore a certain column, otherwise it returns false positive, or a false negative...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a databaser but if you open the file in excel you can select all columns and sort by say a-z in the column that has the actual message and just scan down that column after sort removing duplicates. Granted you want a formula for it, but just wondering if this would be faster than trying to figure out a formula lol. Sorry if I was no help at all.